# What is the order between AsyncTask and normal code?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I added AsyncTask class file to receive Json file from API server.

At that moment, I has wondered about sequence between code of calling AsyncTask and normal code at under the code.

I has known that AsyncTask is executed on background.

If what I understood about AsyncTask is correct, normal code have to be run while AsyncTask code is running.

But My thinking was wrong.

After the Task returned result, normal code start to run!!

I tested this with postDelayed() method and input 5000 milliseconds.

Here's my code

```
try {
    currencyRate = new Task().execute(fromto).get(); // This is calling my AsyncTask class
    Log.e("start", "AsyncTask");
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         double input = Double.parseDouble(et_from.getText().toString());
         double result = Math.round(input * currencyRate * 100.0) / 100.0; 
         tv_to.setText(Double.toString(result));

         Log.e("end", "poatDelayed for 5000 millisec");
    }
}, 5000);
```

difference between 2 logs time was precisely 5000 milliseconds.

I had expected that time will be shorter than 5000 but it was not.

Here's my logcat

```
2023-02-19 23:29:00.294 17115-17115/com.example.moneyexchanger E/start: AsyncTask
2023-02-19 23:29:05.303 17115-17115/com.example.moneyexchanger E/end: poatDelayed for 5000 millisec
```

How could it be???

Comment: Your running your code in an async manner however, you then call .get() which blocks the thread until it completes. If you remove this .get() it should run in the background

Comment: Also note that `AsyncTask` has been deprecated for several years.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand how it works like that.